# Questions about creating a key generator for a license system

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa

I am new at this domain and I have to built a fairly safe license mechanism, but I have some questions about how public key system works.

1. Imagine an implementation of a key generator that uses a private key to generate a string with the MAC and the expiration date. This string will be decrypted by the software and the MAC will be checked to see if it can execute. MY question is: if someone decrypt my message and saw the MAC then it would be fairly easy to create key, wouldn't it? I say that because I know that there is some mathematics behind the fact that you can encrypt with one private key and decrypt with a public one, therefore with the encrypted message, the real message and the public key I guess that someone can find the private key.
2. I am a bit lost in the discussion about if it is necessary to hash some message before the encryption or not. And also the usage of elliptic curves for compression. I would appreciate if someone can give me some info about the topic.

P.S. I am using C++, but any comment in any other language is welcome.

Comment: "therefore with the encrypted message, the real message and the public key I guess that someone can find the private key." - That souldn't be the case for *any* public key algorithm.

Comment: Why not just *sign* the license data with your private key, and verify the signature using the public key embedded in your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an DSA or ECDSA or `<insert favourite sigining algo here>` keypair ... YOU keep the private key safe ... the public key is embedded into your binary

create a datastructure holding your relevant licensing information

compress it

sign it

upon license checking:

verify license signature

uncompress structure

make whatever checks are needed based on license data

---

1. common well known asymetric ciphers are not prone against known plaintext attacks
2. to my knowledge elliptic curves are not used in the context of compression

elliptic curves ARE used in the context of cryptography (read encryption and digital signatures)

3. train your google-fu with: RSA, DSA, ECC (elliptic curve cryptography), ECDSA